# Cant extend into Unallocated space

Tags: partitioning, raspberry-pi

I'm currently messing with my Raspberry Pi, I was going to reinstall the operating system then I realized that only 2.5 gigs was usable on the drive.  I thought this wasn't the problem and continued to install it, but I had to stop the writing session for a personal reason, then I realized again that the partition had been resized to around 55MB, so that means that there is a good 7.29gb that could be used.  I opened up the Disk Managment program and tried to extend the partition, but there was a huge problem:

The space that was allocated could not be extended into the unallocated space, all the options were disabled except for formating.

And with the unallocated space, I can't create anymore volumes or do anything with it, its just wasted space.

Please, I really need this raspberry pi to work, and I don't want to risk destroying another SD card until I know that I can fix this one.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it!

Apparently, the windows built-in partitioner sucks at what it was designed to do. I would recommend if you are stumbling onto this question to use AOMEI Partition Assistant or EaseUS Partition Master, never use the windows partitioner.

Answer (score 1):

Please give some details, maybe a screenshot with the partition configuration/size. Anyway, to bypass eventual limitations you could use a more relible partitioning program. Try [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/875229/cant-extend-into-unallocated-space) .